# Ubuntu 15.10 uses only 1 core

Tags: cpu-load, debugging, system-monitor

System monitor app shows that ubuntu uses only one core 100% (constantly over 99%) and the other 7 are not used at all (0%) also -while one core being at 100%- checking on the processes tab (which I display all + dependencies) all the processes show 0% usage... so what is happening here? At first I thought there is some bug or incompatibility with the app..

but now after opening a few more firefox tabs or trying to do parallel stuff (like installing something while watching a video or what not) ubuntu windows freeze one at a time and unfreeze continue what they are doing including console...

So I guess System Monitor app is right and only 1 core of my cpu is used...

lscpu outputs

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 2
Model name:            AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               1400.000
CPU max MHz:           3500,0000
CPU min MHz:           1400,0000
BogoMIPS:              6984.78
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

lshw -class cpu outputs

```
*-cpu                   
   product: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: cpu@0
   size: 3500MHz
   capacity: 3500MHz
   width: 64 bits
   capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall  nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold vmmcall bmi1 cpufreq
```

I have also a Nvidia GTX 650 Ti as a GPU

I have installed both AMD microcode driver for the CPU and the Nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused because of some application You are running might be a monothread applications, therefore they will use and max out only single core of Your CPU.

Could You post `TOP` result?

You can always reassign process to the other cpu core using

```
taskset -c 0 application
```

It can help to check if You can use other cpu cores with other applications.

To get more accurate real-time info on whats going on You can download `htop` package

```
sudo apt-get install htop
htop
```

Comment: Yea but shouldnt other applications choose an other core if one is like over 99%? I tell you all the time core 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are on 0% usage according to System monitor and only core0 is 100%... this happens if I use only one app no apps or multiple apps 
Anyway I downloaded htop 
it shows on the process tab that 70%-80% of my cpu (although at the top is shows only one green core at 100%and the rest using gray color at 0% ) is used by root under command /usr/bin/pyton /usr/share/system-config-lvm/system-config-lvm.py

Comment: and ~20% is used by firefos under my username. on the  top right corner it sais tasks 136,396 thr 3 running load average 1.6 2.02 2.08

Comment: You should have Your cores listed on the top left corner as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 (assuming 1=0, 2=1)

Comment: yea and as I mentioned in the parethesis of my comment above) only core 1 is colored green and runs at 100% the other cores from 2 to 8 are colored gray and are at 0%

Comment: and on the tabs under the top the process that uses 80% cpu (I dont understand how it derives the "80%" result since only one core is used to 100% according to the same prog) is a process with PID 3758 made by user root and commad is: /usr/bin/pyton /usr/share/system-config-lvm/system-config-lvm.py

Comment: sorry I meant 80%* I edited my last comment according to this.

Comment: i never encouraged such issues, but I'll sure try look into it :)